# Send a service request from an MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a restful web service that generates two types of output based on the URL called. Both methods return some XML logging information.

I'd like to have a button for each type of report on the same view and on return, display the xml data on the screen.

Can anyone provide any guidance or point me in the direction of a tutorial on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery ajax? - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
It lets you specify the type and handle the result pretty easily (this is assuming you mean using ajax for this).

Comment: My first thought was to do the work server side and use the Razor engine to perform the rendering but I'll check out jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it server side, you could use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org) or something similar. Or you could make the request and parse it manually.

Comment: My first thought was to make the requests server side and then pass the returned XML to the view for rendering. Can you have 2 submit buttons on a form with different actions?

Comment: Not the same form to different actions without using javascript. But you can have a check in the action to see which button was clicked and execute different code accordingly. See: http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2009/05/31/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the steer. I've actually used links and then used CSS to make them look like buttons. Once I've finished the main functionality I will come back and re-factor so that I have a single handler in the controller class.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is AJAX.

This link here should help you [Ajax- W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use the jquery ajax method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

and then use the jquery .html method in the success of the ajax call to show the data on the view.

http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2